# Build in XAML a ring of Image objects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, trigonometry

I'm new to WPF and the XAML+C# paradigm troubles me a little... (Maybe more than a little!)

I need to take N Image objects and to position them around the center of a panel at a given radius and each at a 360°/N degrees one apart the other.

It would be very, very simple calculating those coordinates in code using trigonometry and a glorious For cycle... but I need to do that in XAML.

I'm stuck on this atrocious XAML stub:

```
        <Image Name="Cerchietto1" Source="Resources/1.png" Height="{DynamicResource RadiusCerchietti}" Width="{DynamicResource RadiusCerchietti}" Opacity="1" >

            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-32.72"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{DynamicResource RadiusAnelloCerchietti}"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="32.72"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
```

Any help - including a link to a proper tutorial - would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Orf Quarenghi

Comment: You don't do that in XAML. You do that in a custom `Panel` and then you set that `Panel` as the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of an `ItemsControl` or derived control.

Comment: Rusty on my wpf but sounds like something `PathListBox` and `LayoutPaths` could make easier.

Comment: See the [How to create a Custom Layout Panel in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html) page on WPF Tutorial.NET for a quick tutorial on creating custom `Panel`s. You'll see that it's not too complicated... just two methods to implement and that's where you'd put your trigonometry.

Comment: Thanks Sheridan. Following your link I found this: http://jobijoy.blogspot.it/2008/04/simple-radial-panel-for-wpf-and.html

It was exactly what I needed as a starting point.